# Action in RxJava chain not working as it should

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rx-java, chain

I am new to RxJava and RxFirebase and I am making a register system for my app. All the steps in the registrations process need to happen in a sequence and this sequence needs to abort if a step fails.

This is code from my register UI class. I call register() on another class and subscribe on the return value, which is a Maybe.

```
        MyClass.register(username, email, password, photo_uri)
            .subscribe(
                a -> log(a.getUser().getDisplayName()),
                error -> { }                    
            )
```

Inside the register function I have my "chain":

```
    public Maybe<AuthResult> register(String username, String email, String pass, Uri photo_uri) {
        return RxFirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(mAuth, email, pass)
            .doAfterSuccess(authResult -> setFirebaseUsername(authResult.getUser(), username))
            .doAfterSuccess(authResult -> setFirestoreUsername(authResult.getUser(), username));
    }
```

The problem is in the SetFirestoreUsername:

```
        public Completable setFirestoreUsername(FirebaseUser user, String username) {
            HashMap<String, Object> profile_data = new HashMap<>();
            profile_data.put("username", username);

            DocumentReference document = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("users").document(user.getUid());

            // Works
            //RxFirestore.setDocument(document, profile_data).subscribe();

            // Doesn't work
            return RxFirestore.setDocument(document, profile_data);
        }
```

If you take a look at the "works / doesn't work" comments, the difference between the piece of code that works and the code that doesn't is that the latter is returned and used in the subscription chain. I have verified that setFirestoreUsername gets called. The only difference is that when I use return the internal workings of RxFirestore.setDocument simply does not work but no errors are thrown.

Comment: After you returned return `RxFirestore.setDocument(document, profile_data);` Did you subscribe on the result? Because otherwise items will not be emitted.

Comment: Yes, the register function returns an Maybe that has in it a trigger to setFirestoreUsername. In the subscribe code I have shown is where I subscribe to that Maybe. Atleas that's how I understand it. If I place log statements inside setFireStoreUsername they will get displayed as well but the underlying setDocument just doesn't work this way

Comment: I don't see because of chunk of codes... In places, where you receiving this  `return RxFirestore.setDocument(document, profile_data);` Do you have `subscribe()` method on that?

Comment: I improved my post a little bit. Yes, I call subscribe but not directly on RxFirestore.setDocument. This part is returned to the chain and it is on this chain that I subscribe in my register UI class. I have verified that the method gets called. It's just that if I directly call subscribe it works, if I make it part of my chain it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `doAfterSuccess()` operator is called with the value flowing through the pipeline, in your case `setFirestoreUsername(authResult.getUser(), username)`. This is just a method call and the result is not used as part of the observer chain.

Since it is not part of the observer chain, there is no subscription. You may need to use the `flatMapCompletable()` operator instead of `doAfterSuccess()`.

Comment: Thanks, after reading this comment I found more on doAfterSuccess and it suggest the same. I settled for Maybe.flatMap(mymethod).andThen(Maybe.just(valueForNextFlatmap) etc and it works decent.